# gentle way for inserts to sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-core

I want to do inserts in a sql server db with an asp.net core api. 
The data I get includes 9 values and 4 of them are connected to other tables. Is it better to simply try the insert via ef core and catch the sql exception if some values are not in the tables or is it better to look for that before (what means more querys in one api request)? 
If the data is invalid I only do one insert in another table. 
The percentage of invalid data is about 5%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the data from the other table already exists or not.

Also, depending on you DB models configuration, you might end up with duplicate items if you try to insert items that exist, without retrieving and updating them.